# C2371 error because of typedef

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, typedef

May I have a question as "Why following code compile fail with error C2371 at line 04" ?

It succeeded on VS6 but failed on VS2008.

I've tried to comment out line 05, still have this compile error.

```
01   typedef struct tagAAA
02   {
03       unsigned char      a;
04   } AAA;

05   typedef AAA FAR* LPAAA;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because of something that came before.

Comment: Probably because `AAA` is defined somewhere else. As a test try changing `AAA` to something else and see of the error goes away. Also might help to quote the exact error message.

Comment: If you are using C++ to compile this code, you don't need the `typedef struct` as all structures, as classes, can be used as types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably, the compiler gave an error message as well as a code, which told you what the problem is. Googling the code reveals:

```
'identifier' : redefinition; different basic types
```

You say that the error is on line 4; in that case, presumably the identifier is `AAA`, and you've already declared something else called `AAA`.

As to why it succeeds on a 15-year-old pre-standard compiler, you'll have to ask a historian.

Also, get rid of that `typedef struct` nonsense; it's a bad idea in C, and completely pointless in C++. And unless you need to support 16-bit MS-DOS, get rid of that `FAR*` nonsense too; you just need

```
struct AAA {
    unsigned char a;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, I was using the same name conflict with the one that already defined in Windows.
It seems that VS6.0 was not including that file.

Thank you very much for all your support.

Another option is include following macro in the stdafx.h

## define VC_EXTRALEAN        // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers

Answer (score 0):

You don't show us the definition of `FAR` (which can only be a macro here).  I think that there was such a macro in the Microsoft headers back in the 8086 (16 bit MS/DOS) days.  I'm just guessing, but it wouldn't surprise me if they'd kept it around for a while to avoid breaking older code, and only got rid of it after VC6.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6xy3ys5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) that error is "The identifier is already declared."

Which means that the identifier, `AAA`, has already been declared.

So that's the reason.

---

In C++, simply write

```
struct Aaa
{
    unsigned char      a;
};
```

where

- no tag (not needed in C++)
- no typedef of pointer type (an abomination, and also causing problems with applying `const` correctly, e.g. in Microsoft’s own code),
- no `FAR` (MS-DOS is a bit ancient).

Also, using a not-all-uppercase name, to minimize the possibility of *conflict with a macro name*.

Such a conflict *might* be involved in your problem.